# Problem connecting to Mongodb Atlas - Error: "querySrv ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: mongodb

I have created a free cluster for mongodb atlas. Under that cluster I have created a database and a collection to test things out. As I was using node js driver 4.0 or above, this is the connection string I got:

```
mongodb+srv://myName:myPass@cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net/myDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

This is my backend code:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Connection URI
const uri =
    "mongodb+srv://myName:myPass@cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net/myDb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
    try {
        // Connect the client to the server
        await client.connect();
        // Establish and verify connection
        await client.db("myDb").command({ ping: 1 });
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    } finally {
        // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
        await client.close();
    }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

But when I run this code, I get this following error:

```
Error: querySrv ECONNREFUSED _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:210:19) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net'
}
```

Here is some information I can provide:

1. I have whitelisted my current Ip address, After this error I used `0.0.0.0`. But the problem persists.
2. Os: Arch linux
3. I have also tried to use this connection string for older driver version: `mongodb://...` and that worked.

My question: why connection string for node js driver version > 4.0 doesn't work in my case?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: You may want to verify if the connection works (with the same uri) from a tool like `mongosh` or Compass. I don't think the NodeJS Driver version has anything to with that.

Comment: @prasad_ I have also tried mongosh, this was my connection string: `mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username myName`, Then it asks for my password. After writing out the correct password it emits this error: `Error: queryTxt ECONNREFUSED cluster0.2sjva.mongodb.net`

Comment: That error is from the DNS server refusing the connection when the driver tries to resolve the cluster name, it hasn't even attempted to make a network connection to Atlas yet.

Comment: @Joe Thank you! Do you have an idea what should be fixed on my end? :)

Comment: Make sure you are able to resolve the SRV record from the machine running the driver.

Comment: @Joe Thanks again! Do I need to create an SRV record in the first place? :)

Comment: No, it should have been created when you started the cluster in Atlas.